# How to retrive/fetch value from following json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have following json.I want to fetch rdfs:label's value when type is @type": "owl:DbType and rdfs:class is given any class (GreenPlant/GreenPlantHistory)

Ex : If @type": "owl:DbType and class is GreenPlant,fetch rdfs:label's value that is 'Involved' & 'Present'

I have tried following query.But unable to add classname in that.How to do that.

Query : -

```
List<string> jp = v1.Where(i => (string)i["@type"] == "owl:DbType")
  .Select(i => (string)((JObject)i).Properties().First(x => x.Name == "rdfs:label").Value["@value"]).ToList();

{
  "@id": "Ap:Involved",
  "@type": "owl:DbType",
  "rdfs:class": {
    "@id": "Ap:GreenPlant"
  },
  "tag:std:label": {
    "@value": "Involved"
  },
  "rdfs:label": {
    "@value": "Involved"
  },
  "rdfs:range": {
    "@id": "xsd:boolean"
  }
},

{
  "@id": "Ap:Present",
  "@type": "owl:DbType",
  "rdfs:class": {
    "@id": "Ap:GreenPlant"
  },
  "tag:std:label": {
    "@value": "Present"
  },
  "rdfs:label": {
    "@value": "Present"
  },
  "rdfs:range": {
    "@id": "xsd:boolean"
  }
},

{
  "@id": "Ap:UserName",
  "@type": "owl:DbType",
  "rdfs:class": {
    "@id": "Ap:GreenPlantHistory"
  },
  "tag:std:label": {
    "@value": "UserName"
  },
  "rdfs:label": {
    "@value": "UserName"
  },
  "rdfs:range": {
    "@id": "xsd:string"
  }
},

{
  "@id": "Ap:Name",
  "@type": "owl:ObjType",
  "rdfs:class": {
    "@id": "Ap:GreenPlantHistory"
  },
  "tag:std:label": {
    "@value": "Name"
  },
  "rdfs:label": {
    "@value": "Name"
  },
  "rdfs:range": {
    "@id": "xsd:string"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.  Here a is your input json

```
let result = a.filter(elem => elem['@type'] === 'owl:DbType' ).filter(elem2 => {
        let currNode = elem2['rdfs:class'];
        return currNode['@id'] === 'Ap:GreenPlantHistory' || currNode['@id'] === 'Ap:GreenPlant'    
    });
    console.log("result",result);
```

Comment: Hello Anand.I am acessing this code in C# .I am getting error let & filter keyword.

Comment: Hello , my solution is in JavaScript. These functions may not be available in C#

Comment: @Pinky your question has a [javascript] tag and no [c#] tag, therefore it should be no surprise that you get a javascript answer.